# Serialize COM variant to BLOB or IStream

Tags: winapi, com

Is there a standard way to serialize and deserialize a COM VARIANT, e.g. to/from a stream?

Haven't found any in MSDN, an I'm a little surprised now.

Comment: To extend Simon's answer: With ATL development you also have [`CComVariant::WriteToStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkx76the.aspx)

Comment: @RomanR. Actually, I think WriteToStream does a lot less than the RPC marshaler (no decimal, no array, no record, etc.). I may be wrong :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier: Yes but there is a great advantage: the method is available in source code and easily extendable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using the the [VARIANT_UserMarshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

General information on this function (and similar ones for other OLE Automation types) is available here: [Marshaling OLE Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and here: [The type_UserMarshal Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)